# WAMP: VirtualHost not working (Apache 2.4.9)

Tags: windows-7, apache-http-server, virtual-host

I have followed instructions on how to set up VirtualHosts for WAMP (Apache 2.4.9) from many websites, even followed the step by step from [forum.wampserver.com](http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,127757) with no possitive results whatsoever.

Here's a list of my file modifications:

**Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts**

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.0.1   local.ruta.com.ar
::1         localhost
::1         local.ruta.com.ar
```

**apache2.4.9\conf\httpd.conf**

```
# Virtual hosts
Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

**apache2.4.9\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin email@localhost
    DocumentRoot "c:/wamp/www"
    ServerName localhost
    <Directory "c:/wamp/www">
        AllowOverride All
        Options +Indexes
        Require local
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin email@ruta
    DocumentRoot "c:/wamp/www/ruta"
    ServerName local.ruta.com.ar
    ServerAlias www.local.ruta.com.ar
    ErrorLog "logs/ruta.log"
    CustomLog "logs/ruta-access.log" common
    <Directory "c:/wamp/www/ruta">
        AllowOverride All
        Options +Indexes
        Require local
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I'm in Windows 7 64bits, if this matters in any way.
I don't know what else to do. Everything seems fine to me, I checked it many many times and I can't make it work. I tried changing the slashes, the quotes in `Directory` and `DocumentRoot`, remove everything but `DocumentRoot`, `ServerName` and `Directory`...

Point me in the right direction please :( Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you checked the apache (error) logs?

Comment: Yes, many times and there's no errors: http://pastebin.com/tgp643FK

Comment: I tried disabling IPv6 support in Windows and also changing the original port 80 to 8080 but neither of those modifications had any effect at all. I even checked the Firewall and disabling the incoming rules for Apache. Nothing.

Comment: Can you elaborate on "not working" and "no positive results"? What results are you getting and what results did you expect? Can you access only one of the virtual hosts? Do you get any error messages in your browser or (like DavidPostill already asked) in the log files?

Comment: Hi! Error log is on the pastebin up there. "Not working" means I visit `http://local.ruta.com.ar` in Chrome and I get `Error 105 (net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED)`. On the other hand, if I visit `http://localhost`, it works ok and it already worked ok before declaring it as a VirtualHost. I expect to visit `http://local.ruta.com.ar` and get the index.php in the folder `c:/wamp/www/ruta`.